# How to I connect to IBM Netezza using SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to connect to a IBM Netezza server using SQLalchemy. I do that using the create_engine("----") command in which I need to specify a dialect. I can not find a dialect that supports IBM netezza. Is there a way of doing this or should I switch over to pyodbc?

Thank you.

Comment: I've found [this](https://github.com/deontologician/netezza_sqlalchemy).

Comment: Thank you so much. I found this too. But do you suggest trying this out? or using pyodbc. I am not experienced enough to identify a bug. I would end up researching the net to find a fix. what are your thoughts?

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's for you to decide. If you need to use SQLAlchemy, then you have no choice. If you don't use it you'll potentially be looking for solutions to netezza-specific SQL questions anyway.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. :)